# Using Shared Preferences with Log in with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save user details after logging in (with Facebook). I'm able to fetch data but can't save it. I'm using SharedPreferences but can't save it. Data is not lost when I go on some other activity, but when I click back button and re-open this activity, all data is lost. Here is my code:

*Profilee.java*

```
public class Profilee extends Fragment {

    String email1, birthday1, gender1;
    ImageView imageView;
    static int itis = 1;
    TextView texty;
    LoginButton button;
    LinearLayout userinput;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView textView;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    private TextView email, birthday, gende;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;


    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            GraphRequest graphrequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                            if (jsonObject != null) {
                                try {
                                    email1 = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                    gender1 = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                    birthday1 = jsonObject.getString("birthday");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email, gender, birthday");
            graphrequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphrequest.executeAsync();
            AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getContext());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };

    public Profilee() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.getString("name", "asdfgh");
        pref.getString("email", "qwerty");
        pref.getString("gender", "zxcvb");
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilee, container, false);
        button = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        TextView button12 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PrifileEdit.class);
                i.putExtra("st", email1);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        texty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emo);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.asd);
        userinput = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.userdetail);
        int unicode = 0x1F60E;
        String emoji = getEmijoByUnicode(unicode);
        String text = "We will never post on your wall without permission ";
        texty.setText(text + emoji);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CreateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return v;
    }


    public String getEmijoByUnicode(int unicode) {
        return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        gende = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        birthday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.birth);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ViewCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onResume();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    public void displayMessage(final Profile profile) {
        if (itis == 1) {


            if (profile != null) {
                textView.setText(profile.getName());
                email.setText(email1);
                gende.setText(gender1);
                birthday.setText(birthday1);
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                texty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                userinput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("name", String.valueOf(textView));
                editor.putString("email", String.valueOf(email));
                editor.putString("gender", String.valueOf(gende));
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer here to know how to use shared preferences in detail http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-user-sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is because of **displayMessage()** method .

when you reopen this **Activity** , **onResume();** method will call , and then **displayMessage()** .

in **displayMessage()** you are setting **sharedprefrecens** values again , and this work cause you lost previous data from this **sharedprefrecens**.

for solve this problem you must cut **onResume** codes inside **onCreate** method

Comment: actually onCreate() is being called. I also thought onResume() is being called but then i used toast and find out about it

Comment: you must remove all thing form onResume  that cause set new values on your sharedprefrecens

Answer (score 0):

You aren't persisting the data in SharedPreferences correctly. `getText()` will retrieve the text that is currently displayed in the `TextView`, allowing you to store it into SharedPreferences.

```
editor.putString("name", String.valueOf(textView)); // wrong
editor.putString("name", textView.getText().toString()); // right
```

You can then retrieve the value and display it on screen by calling `setText()`.

```
String myEmail = pref.getString("email", "qwerty");
textView.setText(myEmail);
```